# Adding a new data on a new row in CSV file

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, csv, for-loop

I want to add a data from array to CSV file using https://github.com/yaslab/CSV.swift/issues by the way, the way they suggested was each new row need to declare

```
try! csv.write(row: ["", ""])
```

manually, for instance.

```
import Foundation
import CSV

let stream = OutputStream(toFileAtPath: "/path/to/file.csv", append: false)!
let csv = try! CSVWriter(stream: stream)

try! csv.write(row: ["id", "name"])
try! csv.write(row: ["1", "foo"])
try! csv.write(row: ["1", "bar"])

csv.stream.close()
```

Anyway, I need to make it create a new row automatically depends on the number of objects inside the array. So I'd changed it by append each csv into array

```
    func saveCSVFiles() -> URL {
    let itemList = objectNo
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

        let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        csvFile = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName!).csv")
        let path = csvFile

        let stream = OutputStream(url: csvFile!, append: false)
        let csv = try! [CSVWriter(stream: stream!)]
        try! csv[0].write(row: ["name", "x", "y", "width", "height"])

        for no in stride(from: 1, to: itemList.count, by: 1) {
            try! csv[no].write(row: [String(describing: objects.dataName[no]), String(describing: objects.dataX[no]), String(describing: objects.dataY[no]), String(describing: objects.boundingX[no]), String(describing: objects.boundingY[no])])
    }
        csv[itemList.count].stream.close()

        print("yesss!", "\(fileName!)")
    return path!
}
```

but every time I tried to save it cause **Fatal Error: index out of range** on line for-loop and doesn't save at all

Any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in Swift (and most languages) are zero-based. So you want your for loop to go from 0 to count-1. There is a built-in construct, `..<`, thats perfect for that:

```
for no in 0..< itemList.count {
            try! csv[no].write(row: [String(describing: objects.dataName[no]), String(describing: objects.dataX[no]), String(describing: objects.dataY[no]), String(describing: objects.boundingX[no]), String(describing: objects.boundingY[no])])
}
```

### EDIT

It sounds like you need to index into your csv array from 1 to `itemList.count`, and into all your other arrays from 0 to `itemList.count - 1`. Thus you should probably use

```
for no in 0..< itemList.count {
            try! csv[no+1].write(row: [String(describing: objects.dataName[no]), String(describing: objects.dataX[no]), String(describing: objects.dataY[no]), String(describing: objects.boundingX[no]), String(describing: objects.boundingY[no])])
}
```

(note the `+1` in the index into `csv`.)

Comment: but array 0 is belong to line outside the loop because it is a static data just above the for-loop line

Comment: now it's work, it seem the problem is not on the code but on the tableview which read the wrong file

Comment: See the edit on my answer. (I'm not familiar with the CSV library, so I'm guessing on that part.)

Comment: @DuncanC  how can i create new CSV file when CSV file not there, if CSV file exists add Array data to existing CSV file?.can u help how to do it ?